# Session not retaining original value on next page

Tags: php, session

This page shows the status of several chatrooms.  A user can click a button to get them into the room of the person they choose. The nickname session of the person they select should be sent to the room through the form.  The sessions are correct on this page, but when the values are submitted to the room, the nickname changes to the 1st nickname in the database, rather than the one I have passed to the page. How can I get the session to use the data it initially collected? (The page that receives the values only echos sessions, so I didn't post it)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');


$con = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME) or die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT UserType, NickName, Online, InChat FROM main_member WHERE UserType = 2 ORDER BY Online DESC");


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        $UserType = $row['UserType'];
        $NickName = $row['NickName'];
        $Online = $row['Online'];
        $InChat = $row['InChat'];

    $_SESSION['NickName_Session'] = $NickName;

        echo '<table width="353" border="0">';
        echo '<tbody>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="248" height="51">';
        echo Status($Online,$InChat,$NickName); 
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';

     }

function Status($Online,$InChat,$NickName){ 

    if ($Online == 0) {
        echo 'I am not online.';
    }

    elseif($Online == 1 && $InChat == 0){
        echo 'I am online and I will be in my chatroom shortly.';
    }

    elseif($Online == 1 && $InChat == 1){
        echo 'I am online.';
        echo '<form name="get_nickname" id="get_nickname" action="script.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="' . $_SESSION['NickName_Session'] . '">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Start Chat" />';
        echo '</form>';

    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is the script page:

```
session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION['file'])) {
    $_SESSION['file'] = (rand(1000000, 9999999)) . round(10*microtime(TRUE));
}

if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $_SESSION['file'] =  (rand(1000000, 9999999)) . round(10*microtime(TRUE));
}
$url='chat_container.php';
Header("Location: $url");
exit();
```

and here is the chat container where I need the nickname:

```
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');

echo   $_SESSION['NickName_Session'];
```

Comment: Not retaining on next page; is what you posted "the next page"?

Comment: The next page simply echos the sessions.  Nothing more at this point.

Comment: Does `$_POST['nickname']` not have what you need?

Comment: I'm very sure that you have more than one user the of the `UserType = 2` and you are trying to store an array of strings into one string

Comment: It's best to assign a user's row to a session variable; that's how I do it.

Comment: var_dump($_POST); shows array(0) { }

Comment: If POST shows an empty array, then it's time to take out the big guns lol - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Might be an unnamed form element.

Comment: @DarkBee the while loop goes through the array and then assigns the appropriate nickname to each available room.  This is working.  The problem is, it is not submitting the session or anything else through the form.

Comment: How can this be possibly be the right nickname.. Its just assigning the last nickname of the loop to your session. What if you have suddenly 100 users? U'r doing it wrong.. Instead of using the session in the `status` function you should be using the paramter `$nickname`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did that and it says that the variable 'nickname' is not defined.  But it looks like it is to me!

Comment: Try reversing it then `$NickName = $_SESSION['NickName_Session'];`

Comment: and/or changing `$NickName = $row['NickName'];` to `$row['NickName'] = $_SESSION['NickName_Session'];` - Sessions can be tricky.

Comment: @DarkBee  I did it both ways, and the result is the same.  It tells me that nickname is an undefined variable.

Comment: Be sure u use consistent variables, they are case sensitive. Please post the code of your `script.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii- doing each of those things renamed all of the nicknames to the same name.  :(

Comment: The problem may very well lie in the second page. As stated, everything is case-sensitive. If you're not already doing this yet `if(isset($_SESSION['NickName_Session']) && !empty($_SESSION['NickName_Session'])){...}` then that could be a contributing factor.

Comment: It's getting a nickname...just not the right one.  Once it gets to the container page, it's pulling the 1st record that is a usertype 2.  Regardless of which room I try to enter, it keeps just grabbing the 1st one.

Comment: Then you will need to add a session variable to your `WHERE` clause. I.e.: `WHERE UserType = 2 AND NickName = '".$_SESSION['NickName_Session']."'` try that, or something similar to get the username in there. Maybe from your POST variable too.

Comment: It is still not working.  When I do it that way, only one record shows and that is, again, the first record in the db.

Comment: I think you may have a scope issue, or a contributing one. Try changing both `Status($Online,$InChat,$NickName)` to `Status($con,$Online,$InChat,$NickName)`

Comment: Did that, no change.  The form is just not submitting the nickname to the next page, even though the session does show up in the form before submitting.

Comment: Of course not. Thats because the selected nickname is in `$_POST['nickname']`

Comment: Thanks but if that were true, I wouldn't be here.  It is not posting anything.  On the form itself I see that field is populated, it's when I submit to the next page that it does not post anything. $_POST['nickname'] is empty.

Comment: Well then, your form element is probably not named. I.e.: `<input type="text" name="nickname">`

Comment: It is named, but I've decided just to pass that one piece of information through the url, which I don't like to do, but the nickname isn't private anyway so it will work for this.  I'm done pulling my hair out but thank you all for the suggestions!